# How to compare variability between two variables when using the coefficient of variation is inadvisable?

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics

I have two variables with different means. They both include negative and positive values. How can I compare their variability, given that the coefficient of variation should not be used when I have positive and negative values? Are there other measures of relative variability?

```
EDIT
```

Images posted by OP in comments:

[image: Histogram var 1]

and

[image: Histogram of var 2]

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you mean by "relative variability" in a situation where values could be zero or negative?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I want to compare their variability, but since their means are very different, I'd like to compare them on some sort of common ground.

Comment: At a minimum I'd want to see graphs of the data to suggest anything. There is no reason to suggest in advance that a small number of parameters will suffice for simple comparison, let alone what those parameters might be.

Comment: Thanks for you interest @NickCox. Are a couple of histograms enough? http://i.imgur.com/OZAih2l.png and http://i.imgur.com/9v56X38.png

Comment: That helps. I'd report mean, SD, min, p25, med, p75, max as well as show the histograms. Does anyone in power over you insist on a more skeletal report?

Comment: Kind of... Let's say it would be optimal if there was some "unifying statistic" to compare the two distibutions. Anyway, thanks for your help! Much appreciated.